# Loading multilevel XML into MYSQL with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, xml, xpath

I have the following XML file (as a .xml) that I need to import into MySQL.  The issues that I am facing is that it is Multi-level and I don't know how to get the information into the database.

I can load a single level into the database, but as the nodes change for each 'Patient' I assume IF statements would need to be used.

The database output should look like this:

```
link_id          postcode          age          sex          atsi          status          measure_type          measure_done          service_date          measure_value          bp_diastolic          bp_systolic          practice_id     extract_date
-------          --------          ---          ---          ----          ------          ------------          ------------          ------------          -------------          ------------          -----------          -----------     ------------
Patient 1        1234              50           2            4             c               BP                    True                  22011999              null                   80                    128                  DEMO            2015-07-13T14:45:55.876Z
Patient 1        1234              50           2            4             c               CHOLESTEROL           True                  05061998              7.2                    null                  null                 DEMO            2015-07-13T14:45:55.876Z
Patient 1        1234              50           2            4             c               HAEMOGLOBIN           True                  05061998              134                    null                  null                 DEMO            2015-07-13T14:45:55.876Z
Patient 2        4567              21           1            2             P               BP                    True                  18062014              null                   72                    135                  DEMO            2015-07-13T14:45:55.876Z
Patient 2        4567              21           1            2             P               HEIGHT                True                  22011999              161.0                  null                  null                 DEMO            2015-07-13T14:45:55.876Z
Patient 2        4567              21           1            2             P               LDL                   True                  05061998              5.00                   null                  null                 DEMO            2015-07-13T14:45:55.876Z
```

Each individul measurement needs it's own row in the database and pulls information from both the data and patient nodes.

I have tried, unsuccessfully using XPath.

Here is the XML:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1252"?>
<MedicalMicrodata xmlns="URL HERE">
  <data>
    <practice_id>DEMO</practice_id>
    <extract_date>2015-07-13T14:45:55.876Z</extract_date>
    <population_count>123</population_count>
    <extractor_details>Demonstration 123</extractor_details>
    <patient>
      <link_id>Patient 1</link_id>
      <postcode>1234</postcode>
      <age>50</age>
      <sex>2</sex>
      <atsi>4</atsi>
      <active>False</active>
      <status>C</status>
      <measurements>
        <bp>
          <bp_diastolic>80</bp_diastolic>
          <bp_done>True</bp_done>
          <bp_service_date>22011999</bp_service_date>
          <bp_systolic>128</bp_systolic>
        </bp>
        <cholesterol>
          <cholesterol_done>True</cholesterol_done>
          <cholesterol_service_date>05061998</cholesterol_service_date>
          <cholesterol_value>7.2</cholesterol_value>
        </cholesterol>
        <haemoglobin>
          <haemoglobin_done>True</haemoglobin_done>
          <haemoglobin_service_date>05061998</haemoglobin_service_date>
          <haemoglobin_value>134.00</haemoglobin_value>
        </haemoglobin>
      </measurements>
    </patient>
    <patient>
      <link_id>Patient 2</link_id>
      <postcode>4567</postcode>
      <age>21</age>
      <sex>1</sex>
      <atsi>2</atsi>
      <active>False</active>
      <status>P</status>
      <measurements>
        <bp>
          <bp_diastolic>72</bp_diastolic>
          <bp_done>True</bp_done>
          <bp_service_date>18062014</bp_service_date>
          <bp_systolic>135</bp_systolic>
        </bp>
        <height>
          <height_done>True</height_done>
          <height_service_date>22011999</height_service_date>
          <height_value>161.0</height_value>
        </height>
        <ldl>
          <ldl_done>True</ldl_done>
          <ldl_service_date>05061998</ldl_service_date>
          <ldl_value>5.00</ldl_value>
        </ldl>
      </measurements>
    </patient>
  </data>
</MedicalMicrodata>
```

Sample of XPATH code

```
$header_path=$xml->xpath("data");
$patient_path=$xml->xpath("data/patient");
$bp_path=$xml->xpath("data/patient/measurements/bp");
$cholesterol_path=$xml->xpath("data/patient/measurements/cholesterol");
$haemoglobin_path=$xml->xpath("data/patient/measurements/haemoglobin");
$hba1c_path=$xml->xpath("data/patient/measurements/hba1c");
$hdl_path=$xml->xpath("data/patient/measurements/hdl");
$height_path=$xml->xpath("data/patient/measurements/height");
$ldl_path=$xml->xpath("data/patient/measurements/ldl");
$rbg_path=$xml->xpath("data/patient/measurements/random_blood_glucose");
$triglycerides_path=$xml->xpath("data/patient/measurements/triglycerides");
$weight_path=$xml->xpath("data/patient/measurements/weight");

if (!$header_path) {
    foreach ($header_path as $header) {

        $extract_date = $header["extract_date"];
        $practice_id = $header["practice_id"];

        echo $practice_id;

            if ($patient_path) {

                $postcode = $patient["postcode"];
                $age = $patient["age"];
                $sex = $patient["sex"];
                $atsi = $patient["atsi"];
                $status = $patient["status"];


                    // BP                    
                    if ($bp_path) {

                        foreach ($bp_path as $bp) {

                            $measure_done = $bp["bp_done"];
                            $service_date = $bp["bp_service_date"];
                            $bp_diastolic = $bp["bp_diastolic"];
                            $bp_systolic = $bp["bp_systolic"];

                            $sql = "INSERT INTO 'nkpi_pat_measure' (postcode, age, sex, atsi, status, measure_type, measure_done, service_date, bp_diastolic, bp_systolic, practice_id, extract_date) 
                                    VALUES ('$postcode', '$age','$sex','$atsi','$status','BP','$measure_done', '$service_date','$bp_diastolic','$bp_systolic','$practice_id','$extract_date')";
                                    $result = $sqlconn->prepare($sql);
                                    $result->execute();

                        }
                    }
```

Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Adrian.

Comment: Do you want get data through SQL query or PHP XML parsing?

Comment: I don't know sorry.
I just want the data out of the XML and into an SQL table

Comment: With that kind of table, this is possible with xpath. Perhaps even directly with a commandline client. of mysql. I can't understand your question that it didn't work for you, at least it could have worked (but you don't show what you're tried so far so there is little to add).

Comment: Thanks @hakre, I have added a sample of the code

Answer (score 1):

Based on your table structure it is mainly elbow grease from here: Create a data transfer object (php class) for the patient object, measurements object for measurement, and 2 tables:

Table patient:

> Table patient has address information and other personal information

```
CREATE TABLE patient (
patient_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
{other patient data}
) ENGINE=InnoDB ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED KEY_BLOCK_SIZE=4; /* While we are there, lets save some storage space */
```

Add a unique index on patient so a patient record can be inserted only once.

Table measurements:

> Table measurements has the measurements.

This is all normalized:
Measurements are stored as:

```
 <measurements>
    <bp>
      <bp_diastolic>80</bp_diastolic>
      <bp_done>True</bp_done>
      <bp_service_date>22011999</bp_service_date>
      <bp_systolic>128</bp_systolic>
    </bp>
    <cholesterol>
      <cholesterol_done>True</cholesterol_done>
      <cholesterol_service_date>05061998</cholesterol_service_date>
      <cholesterol_value>7.2</cholesterol_value>
    </cholesterol>
    <haemoglobin>
      <haemoglobin_done>True</haemoglobin_done>
      <haemoglobin_service_date>05061998</haemoglobin_service_date>
      <haemoglobin_value>134.00</haemoglobin_value>
    </haemoglobin>
  </measurements>

CREATE TABLE measurements(
measurements_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
patient_id INT NOT NULL,
done BOOLEAN,
service_date DATE,
medical_data_identifier VARCHAR(200),
measured_value TEXT,
FOREIGN KEY (patient_id) REFERENCES patient(patient_id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED KEY_BLOCK_SIZE=4; /* While we are there, lets save some storage space */
```

The trick is in the model 1:n: 1 patient, multiple measurements, without repeating any data.

The second trick is in medical_data_identifier:

> medical_data_identifier is structured as follows:
>   * 1 or multiple records per test.

This would lead to 2 records for the systolic/diastolic. >medical_data_identifier=systolic

> value=128
>
> medical_data_identifier=diastolic
>
> value=72

Risk: Multiple tests on 1 day. To counter that you can do something else: Store a test as a json or xml:

> medical_data_identifier=bloodpressure
>
> value=80128

It depends on the use in choosing what to use. There are other solutions too:
XML or JSON format columns (use mariadb instead of mysql for this: 100% compatible, but just more options).

Or parent column identifying the parent data for a test.

Or a test identifier table in between getting you a 1:N:M data model with 3 tables:

- Patient
- test
- measurements

With a key relation between them.

And then you just write a piece of php code to insert all of this.